# Ctrl-Tab behavior in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012

Question:  Is there a way to make "ctrl + tab" behavior the same in VS2012 **as it used to be in VS2010**?

Specifically, I noticed that when you hold control and hit tab a few times, the list on the screen now **ALSO** includes windows that you wouldn't normally care about (much less want to switch focus to) such as:  "Find Results 1", "Error List", and "Output".

These are those standard windows you typically have positioned at the bottom of your Visual Studio environment.  Before, in VS2010, these types of items would not be included in the list.  It was simply and easy to Ctrl-Tab to only the documents you had open.  I use this feature *quite a lot* in order to quickly navigate amongst open files.

But now in VS2012, when you hit Ctrl-Tab and suddenly your focus is down in the error list.... its like.... what were they thinking??  You have to hit tab again to get past these useless choices, which just slows me down.  If anyone knows a way to turn off this horrible new "feature", please let me know!  :)

Comment: On which side do toy see the tab labelled Error List? Can you show us a screenshot of your Ctrl+Tab popup?

Comment: You were right on the money.  Thanks very much!!  My group of windows had the tabs on top.  I repositioned the windows so that the tabs were on the bottom, which fixed the issue.  It is funny that positioning them differently causes them to be treated as "documents" versus "tool windows".  I didn't even know there was a difference before now...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This does not happen normally.
You probably docked those windows as documents rather than as tool windows.

To check whether that's true, try docking a regular document window to the side; if you can't, that would mean that you have a vertical document split.

To fix it, undock those windows, then re-dock them using the lowest arrow.

Comment: As a side note, the ctrl-tab window that pops up will also list the tools windows down the left side and the document windows down the right side. So you can see at a glance how you have them docked.